# Is there a classification system where the sum of the digits are a factor?

Tags: number-systems

This may be confusing. An example:

12

1+2=3

3 is a factor of 12.

135

1+3+5=9

9 is a factor of 135.

555

5+5+5=15

15 is a factor of 555.

What is the name of this classification system or did I create a new one?

Comment: This looks related to the fact that a number (in base 10) is a multiple of 3 if and only if the sum of its digits is a multiple of 3.  Have you found any examples that are not multiples of 3?

Comment: What makes this a "classification system"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I didn't know the right term. Kind of like prime, parity, Fibonacci, that stuff. Also, It seems that it's either 3 or 7 that works.

Comment: @BrianHopkins It is easy to find examples that ar not multiples of 3. Try 476 or 999796

Comment: I still need to know the name of this if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

These are called [Harshad Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harshad_number) (or Niven numbers).

> In mathematics, a harshad number (or Niven number) in a given number
> base is an integer that is divisible by the sum of its digits when
> written in that base.

Comment: Nice to know.  Here's the OEIS entry [A005349](https://oeis.org/A005349) with several references.  There's an interesting subsequence called the Moran numbers [A001101](https://oeis.org/A001101) where the number divided by the sum of its digits is prime.

Comment: @BrianHopkins Thanks. Actually OEIS was how I found the name, but I forgot to include that link.

Comment: Nice, thanks for answering for me!